# How to handle additional data GCM in iOS remote messages

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, remote-notifications

I am receiving remote notifications via Google Cloud Messages. A message pops up, a badge gets attached to the app item, also the sound works fine. Now I am trying to access additional data but struggle a bit. That's how the message looks like:

```
Notification received: [gcm.notification.shops: ["548","525"], gcm.message_id: 0:1472546619970126%1dfec10a1dfec10a, gcm.notification.vibrate: 1, aps: {
alert =     {
    body = "2 neue Gutscheine verf\U00fcgbar";
    title = "Neue Gutscheine";
};
  badge = 2;
  "content-available" = 1;
  sound = 1;
}]
```

How can I now access the shops array? This does not work:

```
var shops :[String] = userInfo["shops"] as! [String]
```

I am trying to handle it in the didReceiveRemoteNotification() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the element from an array to a string an turning it into an array at the very end did the trick:

```
 if let v = userInfo["gcm.notification.shops"] as? NSString{
   let new_vouchers_string = v.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
   let new_vouchers = new_vouchers_string.map { Int($0)!}
 }
```